# ASP MVC strongly typed html without razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to be able to do things like:

```
<input name=@Model.SomeProperty (as the actual property name and not its value)  value=@Model.SomeProperty type="text/>
```

so that model binding still works, but I don't need to use the Razor helpers.

Comment: You should not have edited : the answer will be : use HtmlHelpers (and they'll be right !)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus I thought about that and realised that they do have value in some situations, but damn can they be irritating for simple things!, so I rephrased my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Helper Method that return your DisplayName:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetPropertyName<TModel, TProperty>( this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression )
        {
            var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TProperty>(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
            string value = metaData.PropertyName ?? expressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(value);
        }
```

And then you just use:  @Html.GetPropertyName(m => m.SomeProperty)

Comment: I like this idea a lot, then I can only use the Razor helpers where they actually add value, like the Validation helpers, and not use them for trivial things like combo boxes, text boxes, forms, urls etc where I find they just get in the way.

Comment: I do of course realise the irony in using a Razor helper to avoid using Razor helpers:)

Comment: Well, it is up to you... I personally think my Views are way more clean using @Html.TextBoxFor instead of writing all the html myself.